# Missing values in pgfplots with error bars

Tags: pgfplots

pgfplots can deal with missing values in table inputs by either skipping or jumping over any values which are given as `nan` in the input table file, as discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28792/pgfplot-missing-values-in-table-data). I want to do a similar thing with error bar plots. In particular, several entries of the table column where errors are given are set to `nan`, as in the code example below. I'd like to have a result where error bars are only plotted on points where non-`nan` values are available.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{filecontents}{tabletest.data}
x  ind2    ind3
0  0.22507 0.99741
1  0.22507 nan
2  0.22507 0.99741
3  0.22507 nan
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=x,ylabel=y,no markers]
\addplot plot[error bars/.cd,y dir=plus,y explicit,error mark=diamond*] 
  table[x=x,y=ind2,y error=ind3] {tabletest.data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, compilation fails with the errors `Missing number, treated as zero.` and `Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).` When replacing `nan` by numeric values, the file compiles, but of course has error bars on all points.

Is there another reasonably way to get error bars only on part of the plotted points from table data, or is this a missing feature in pgfplots?

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53232/plots-with-only-a-few-shifted-error-bars) has an answer suggesting the use of gnuplot, but I'd like to do it without gnuplot.

Comment: Ah, it does indeed seem like this is a missing feature. It works if you provide the data as a `coordinates` list, so PGFplots definitely has the capability to omit error bars for some values, it just doesn't parse the `table` data correctly in this case. You might want to open a feature request at the [Sourceforge site](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=224188&atid=1060659)

Comment: @Jake Before that the starred version of the `filecontents` environment should be used. But still I couldn't make it work.

Comment: @percusse: Why should the starred version be used here? The info lines added by the unstarred `filecontents` environment don't do any harm (lines starting with `#` or `%` are ignored).

Comment: @Jake You are right it doesn't do harm. I've changed two things at a time before the test which mislead me. But still there is no need to add info lines anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a missing feature in pgfplots 1.5.1 . It will be present in the next stable after 1.5.1 (probably 1.6).